# To fetch data from webservices, Shall we use AsyncTaskLoader or just AsyncTask?

Tags: android, android-asynctask, asynctaskloader

can we replace asynctask with asynctaskloader?is there a way to use asynctaskloader which receive int parameter and return string parameter.I am talking about loadinBackground method.In asynctask loadinbackground can take parameter while in asynctaskloader loadInBackground i do not find an example where this method takes parameter.Is it possible.Can anybody give me an example.Anybody helps me is greatly appreciated.

Comment: write your custom ContentProvider and use standard CursorLoader

Comment: Can someone give me some idea how to do it?

Comment: see http://developer.android.com/training/load-data-background/setup-loader.html